# Passing a JSON object to handlebars template from Node Server

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to pass the query result to a handlebars page. The query result is taken as shown below:

```
        connection.query("select * from members",function(err,rows){
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                var data = rows; //tried JSON.stringify, JSON.parse, both 
                console.log(data);
                /*
                [{"username":"a@xyz.com","manager_id":"one"},
                 {"username":"b@xyz.com","manager_id":"two"},
                 {"username":"c@xyz.com","manager_id":"three"}]
                */
                res.render('handlebarsPage',{data:data});
            }      
          }
```

However in the handlebarsPage, I cannot access the data using:

```
 {{data[0].username}}  // Parse Error
```

Please suggest the right way to achieve this in handlebars

```
<%= data[0].username %> // works fine in ejs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following:

```
{{data.[0].username}} or
{{data.0.username}}
```

Comment: both worked fine :) Sometimes, things are so close yet so far! :P